# Looking for solution to `Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON:...`

Tags: json, amazon-dynamodb, command-line-interface, aws-cloud9

I'm trying to use AWS Cloud9 IDE in the CLI to create a table in AWS DynamoDB, then have a .json file filled with 20 items and use the CLI to upload those 20 items to the DynamoDB table with a variety of other attributes as well. I've created the table sucessfully but when I go to write the .json file to the table I recieved an error.

I made sure I was in the same directory as my .json file in the CLI in Cloud9. and ran

`voclabs:~/environment/Homework2 $ aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://sensor_items.json`

which returned

```
Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Invalid JSON:
[
 {
   "Sensor": {"S": "Sensor1"},
   "SensorDescription": {"S": "Description 1"},
   "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/images/sensor1.jpg"},
   "SampleRate": {"N": 2048},
   "Locations": {"SS": ["Aberdeen MD", "Warren MI", "Orlando FL"]}
 },
 {
   "Sensor": {"S": "Sensor2"},
   "SensorDescription": {"S": "Description 2"},
   "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/images/sensor2.jpg"},
   "SampleRate": {"N": 4096},
   "Locations": {"SS": ["New York NY", "Chicago IL"]},
   "SensorFunctional": {"BOOL": true}
 },
 {
    "Sensor": {"S": "Sensor3"},
    "ImageFile": {"S": "/Sensors/images/sensor3.jpg"},
    "SampleRate": {"N": 2829},
    "Locations": {"SS": ["San Fransisco, CA", "Las Vegas, NV"]}
 },....
```

I'm thinking that maybe my formatting is incorrect in my .json file but I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: Also to create my table I used the following: `aws dynamodb create-table --table-name Sensors --attribute-definitions AttributeName=Sensor,AttributeType=S --key-schema AttributeName=Sensor,KeyType=HASH --provisioned-throughput ReadCapacityUnits=5,WriteCapacityUnits=5`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON does not match the payload expected by a BatchWriteItem:

```
{
   "RequestItems": { 
      "TableName" : [ 
         { 
            "PutRequest": { 
               "Item": { 
                  "string" : { 
                     "B": blob,
                     "BOOL": boolean,
                     "BS": [ blob ],
                     "L": [ 
                        "AttributeValue"
                     ],
                     "M": { 
                        "string" : "AttributeValue"
                     },
                     "N": "string",
                     "NS": [ "string" ],
                     "NULL": boolean,
                     "S": "string",
                     "SS": [ "string" ]
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      ]
   },
   "ReturnConsumedCapacity": "string",
   "ReturnItemCollectionMetrics": "string"
}
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_BatchWriteItem.html

You have to have your JSON nested inside the table name along with the PutRequest parameter.